# MATLAB `convnhulln` doesn't support Qhull normals option?

Tags: matlab, convex-hull, convex, qhull

Suppose I have a set of vertices, e.g. `V = [ 0 0 ; 1 0 ; 0 1]` and I want to construct their convex hull in MATLAB. Using the `convhulln` command, I can extract the vertex indices for the facets of the hull e.g. `convhulln(V)` yields

```
ans =
     1     2
     2     3
     3     1
```

(I ultimately want to consider a convex hull in 6D space, so the `convhull` command would not be appropriate.)  What I'm really interested in, though, is the explicit H-representation, i.e. the surface normals and offsets for the hyperplanes that each facet lies on. This corresponds to the 'n' option in Qhull, which `convhulln` is stated to use. But the command `convhulln(V,{'n'})` just gives back the same output as above. Am I missing something, or does MATLAB simply not support the 'n' option from Qhull?